# Python & Pandas Iteration Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I am trying to get an iteration of every state from quandl, however unless I just have the query be `print(X)`, it only returns one string for `abbv` instead of listing all 50 states and joining them together. Any reason for this?

Thanks.

```
for abbv in fiddy_states[0][0][1:]:
    query = "FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv)
    df = quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)

    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df)
```

[image]

Comment: can you post an output of `print(fiddy_states[0][0])`?

Comment: Row 1:  0     Abbreviation      Row 2:     1               AL       Row t+2 = etc

Comment: I found a way to get this to work, however this creates mutiple columns tat start with 'Value' . Any Ideas on how to get the columns to reflect only [abbv] values?for abbv in states:
           { main_df = main_df.join(df,lsuffix=abbv) }

Comment: please [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38128037/edit) sample and desired data sets

Comment: Posted picture of main_df